# my OnItemClickListener and OnItemLongClickListener didn't function at all

Tags: android, onitemlongclicklistener

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    final Context context = this;
    ListAdapter boxAdapter;
     String[] dataArray;
     EditText editText;
     //name that get back through the dialog
     private String getName;
     private String selectedItem;   
     private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;        // The list adapter





      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        fillData();
        boxAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, products);

        ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
        lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);


        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddItem);



        //the add item button function
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //get the dialog view
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.insert);


                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        // get user input and set it to result
                                        // edit text
                                         getName=userInput.getText().toString();
                                         products.add(new Product(getName,false));

                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();




            }

        });






        // Create the listener for normal item clicks
        OnItemClickListener itemListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long rowid) {

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "You have clicked on " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + ".",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };




        //the long press to delete function

        OnItemLongClickListener itemLongListener = new OnItemLongClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                 // Store selected item in global variable
                selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage("Do you want to remove " + selectedItem + "?");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        products.remove(selectedItem);
                        boxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                selectedItem + " has been removed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // Create and show the dialog
                builder.show();

                // Signal OK to avoid further processing of the long click
                return true;
            }


            };

            lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(itemListener);
            lvMain.setOnItemLongClickListener(itemLongListener);

        }



      void fillData() {

          dataArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ChecklistData);
          for(String productName : dataArray)
          {
            products.add(new Product(productName,false));
          }

      }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




    }
```

This is ListAdapter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<Product> objects;

    ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
        ctx = context;
        objects = products;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

        Product p = getProduct(position);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.name);
        /*((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice)).setText(p.price + "");
        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.image);*/

        CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
        cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
        cbBuy.setTag(position);
        cbBuy.setChecked(p.box);
        return view;
    }

    Product getProduct(int position) {
        return ((Product) getItem(position));
    }

    ArrayList<Product> getBox() {
        ArrayList<Product> box = new ArrayList<Product>();
        for (Product p : objects) {
            if (p.box)
                box.add(p);
        }
        return box;
    }

    OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).box = isChecked;
        }
    };
}
```

OnItemClickListener and OnItemLongClickListener didn't function at all. Anyone help me out here.. I did diagnose the problem but it still doesn't have function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. implement View.OnItemClickListener and AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener and their corresponding methods in your class.
2. initialize your views correctly (findViewById...)
3. set click listeners to your views (button.setOnClickListener(this) / button.setOnLongClickListener(this)
4. react to the push events in the implemented methods like:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.button:
               this.doSomething();
       }
   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       //react to the view or react to the position
       switch (view.getId()) {

           case R.id.button:
               this.doSomething();
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
OnItemClickListener itemListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
OnItemLongClickListener itemLongListener = new OnItemLongClickListener() {
```

You just define those variables but you don't assign them to your ListView.
You should call these lines somewhere:

```
lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(itemListener);
lvMain.setOnItemLongClickListener(itemLongListener);
```

**UPDATE:**

You also miss to register the list for context menu.

```
registerForContextMenu(lvMain);
```

Comment: is it means I need to put `OnItemLongClickListener itemLongListener = new OnItemLongClickListener() {` into OnItemClickListener?

Comment: where should I put this line?  `registerForContextMenu(lvMain);`

Comment: You can put it to onCreate(), after you have the reference to lvMain.

Comment: I have put the line at the right place but it still can't click or long click

Comment: Hmm, it should work. Do you see any suspicious in the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register listeners. Add following lines to the end of your `onCreate()` method.

```
lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(itemListener);
lvMain.setOnItemLongClickListener(itemLongListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. When onclick or onlongclick are enabled in the Layout; onitemclickListener wont work. Just remove the tags android:clickable and android:longclickable from your Layout XML resource and it will all work.